# How do I /give myself a named pickaxe with unbreakable in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am on Minecraft pocket edition version 1.2.10.1, and am trying to use the following command:

`/give @p stone_pickaxe 1 0 {display:{Name:"The Stone Breaker"},Unbreakable:"1"}`

When trying to use this command, it returns `Line 1 Column 2 Missing '}' or object member name.` Could someone point out what is wrong with my command?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the thing is is that the command you have isn't allowed on Bedrock Edition. Renaming and enchanting items are only available on Java Edition.

Answer (score -1):

Simple. The  {display:{Name:"The Stone Breaker"},Unbreakable:"1"} command doesn’t work in mcpe

Comment: What does work then?

Comment: @TimmyJim To be fair, that's not the question. The original question wants to know what's wrong with the command they showed - this answer is pretty straight-to-the-point.

Comment: @MageXy this answer could however be improved if it were to give an alternate command that would work in mcpe.